# Which mysql select is better/faster?

Tags: sql, mysql, performance

Is there a preferred way? There are currently 1640 rows in the `game` table to go through and will be adding about 1200 every year.

```
SELECT `date` FROM `game` WHERE `date`<'2009-11-09' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1;
```

0.0004 seconds

```
SELECT MAX(`date`) AS `date` FROM `game` WHERE `date`<'2009-11-09' LIMIT 1;
```

0.0006 seconds

The speeds were for the first time this ran. Each time after was 0.0002 for each.

mySQL:
Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server version: 5.1.37

PHP (shouldn't be relevant):
5.x

Comment: The LIMIT is surplus to requirements in the second query - there will be only one MAX().

Comment: You might get a definite answer by running an explain statement which according to documentation is:

explain [select statement]

Although the performance might change, when you get to a higher amount of data in the table.

Comment: @martin: Not quite - there could be 2+ records with the same value; any one could be returned because of the `LIMIT 1`.  See my answer for more details.

Comment: That's assuming date only, no time portion.  Unless the date is coming from the application and not via SQL...

Comment: `date` is stored as YYYY-MM-DD. There are MANY instances/row where the date is duplicated. In the 1600 current entries, "SELECT DISTINCT `date` FROM `game`" gives 66 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply MySQL [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html) and check the query plans.  The second example may well have a cleaner plan, which is nice as it looks cleaner to my eye.  (Once you remove the limit.)

A noddy test locally shows (no indexes).

Query 1:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT  datex
FROM    TABLE_X x
WHERE   datex < "2009-10-20"
ORDER BY datex DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Plan

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key  key_len ref  rows Extra
1  SIMPLE      x     ALL  NULL          NULL NULL    NULL 2    Using where; Using filesort
```

Query 2:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT  MAX( datex )
FROM    TABLE_X x
WHERE   datex < "2009-10-20"
```

Plan

```
id  select_type table type  possible_keys   key     key_len ref   rows Extra
1   SIMPLE      x     ALL   NULL            NULL    NULL    NULL  2    Using where
```

Comment: An explain will not tell you how fast it will run.

Comment: @jle: An explain plan tells you how efficiently the query is.  Better the efficiency, better the performance...

Answer (score 1):

With those numbers of rows and the simplicity of the queries, it should not matter.  You also do not need the limit on the second query.  Just choose whichever one is easier for you to understand.

Comment: Agreed - unless the difference between 4 ten-thousands of a second and 6 ten-thousands of a second is significant to your application ;-)

Comment: I do realize it's a small database, but I'm looking to learn best practices along the way, so if it should ever be a large database...

Comment: Best practice is to rarely to out-guess the query optimizer, which is what I think the first query is, even though you may be right, this time. Best practice is more writing what you mean so that later when some one reads it, there is no 'huh?' factor. My vote is for query 2.

Answer (score 1):

In second query you don't have to add `LIMIT 1`. It will always return 1 row. I would say that **second query is more readable** and you should use. But I agree with @jle. You have very small database and it really does not affect performance very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at what the plan is (ie how mysql does the work) using explain - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

I imagine they are pretty much identical, but that's the best way to check (it may depend on indices etc).

But I have to ask - do you really need to worry about this?  It's not exactly slow, and the table isn't growing at a huge rate.

Finally, you don't need the second "limit".

Answer (score 0):

I would also want to add to all the other responses:

try to add a million records. Best way to know for sure.